# django-ckeditor :data not loading in the Form

Tags: python, django, django-ckeditor

I'm Using Django-ckeditor as a model form widget.I have been able to able to save data using the model-form.

Now that I want to edit any saved data the form does not load the data onto the CKeditor.
Django 1.10 Python 3.5 Windows 7 64bit

**forms.py**

```
class templateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = presciptiontemplates
        fields = ['template', 'templateid', ]
        widgets = {
            'template': CKEditorWidget(),
        }
        labels = {
            "templateid": _("Patient ID"),
            }
```

**views.py**

```
def get_template(request, tid):
template = presciptiontemplates.objects.get(templateid=tid)
form = templateform(request.POST, instance=template)
if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.patientid = tid
        form.save()
else:
    form = templateform(request.POST, instance=template)
return render(request, 'presapp/viewtemplate.html',{'form': form})
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="preview-content">
    <form method="post" style="margin-top:20px;">
        {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.media }}
         {{ form|safe }}
        <div class="" style="margin-top:20px ;">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light left" type="submit">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">add_circle</i
    </button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try removing |safe just use {{ form }}

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal it doesn't work that way either Also tried with form as paragraph and table

Answer (score 0):

Change {{ form|safe }} to {{ form.as_p }}

```
<div id="preview-content">
        <form method="post" style="margin-top:20px;">
            {% csrf_token %}
             {{ form.media }}
             {{ form.as_p }}
            <div class="" style="margin-top:20px ;">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light left" type="submit">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">add_circle</i
        </button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```